# How do get the surface pro 3 to type and click

Tags: keyboard, surface

I have the surface pro 3. When I use Ubuntu I am unable to type or click. I can still move the mouse around. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need kernel 3.19.0 or later ... upgrade to latest (or wait until 15.04 comes out)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I suggest expanding this with more information, specifically about (1) what changed, so that it works with that kernel version, and (2) how to upgrade (and if you think some people are better off waiting, then perhaps some information on the advantages of that).